# Have all the symmetries of the standard model of particle physics been found?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, conservation-laws, standard-model, group-theory

**Background**

- The standard model of particle physics is entirely determined by writing down its Lagrangian or, equivalently, writing down the corresponding system of PDEs.
- Every set of PDEs has a corresponding set of "continuous symmetries" (essentially continuous changes of variables). The well-known (non-discrete) symmetries of the standard model are examples of these.
- There are tools for computing all the symmetries of a given set of PDEs (or at least for generating constraining relationships between the symmetries). One source for these tools is *Applications of Lie Groups to Partial Differential Equations* by Peter J. Olver.

**Question**

Have the above-mentioned symmetry-finding techniques been applied to the standard model as a whole? Or even to part of it? In other words, do we know *all* of the symmetries of the standard model or some part of it? We obviously know some because the standard model was built to have them, but my question is whether the existence of other symmetries has been ruled out.

Answer (score 26):

> The standard model of particle physics is entirely determined by writing down its Lagrangian or, equivalently, writing down the corresponding system of PDEs.

Actually, this isn't true -- it is true *classically*, but *quantum mechanically* the Lagrangian alone does not define the quantum theory. You also need to define a regularization/renormalization prescription for dealing with divergences. As as result, there actually can be symmetries of the classical action that are not symmetries of the quantum theory -- this situation is called an [anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_(physics)). One can think of anomalies as arising due to the failure of the path integral measure to be invariant under symmetries of the classical Lagrangian.

The standard model has a famous [chiral anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_anomaly), and Yang-Mills theory (on which, eg, QCD is based) generically has a [conformal anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_anomaly) which can [win you a million dollars if you can rigorously prove exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_existence_and_mass_gap) and which [explains most of the mass of the proton and neutron (and therefore most of your mass)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_anomaly#QCD). (It's a common misconception that all mass in the Standard Model comes from the Higgs mechanism).

Furthermore, there can be quantum mechanical relationships between different theories that are not obvious classically. The most famous example is the [AdS/CFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdS/CFT_correspondence) duality, which is a quantum mechanical equivalence between two theories in different numbers of dimensions.

These kinds of relationships show up even in theories closer to the Standard model, (ie, without gravity), like $N=4$ super Yang-Mills theory (quoting from https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1095):

> In this paper we argue that the planar scattering amplitudes in N = 4 SYM theory have a
> hidden symmetry that we call dual superconformal symmetry. It appears on top of all well-known
> symmetries of the scattering amplitudes (supersymmetry, conformal symmetry, etc.) and is not
> related (not in an obvious way, at least) to an invariance of the Lagrangian of the theory

As far as I know, there is no systematic procedure to look for all of these kinds of "hidden" quantum mechanical symmetries.

Therefore, it is entirely possible that there are hidden symmetries of the Standard Model, that we have not been able to detect with our current tools.